# Private property may still be null after checking that it is not null. Why?

Tags: typescript

For the following code, I'll check in `testMethod()` if any of my properties are `null` and if they are, return.

```
class TestClass {
    #private_property: string[] | null;
    public_property: string[] | null;

    constructor() {
        this.#private_property = null;
        this.public_property = null;
    }

    testMethod() {
        if (this.#private_property == null)
            return;
        if (this.public_property == null)
            return;

        this.#private_property
        this.public_property
    }
}
```

I should be able to conclude that after those to checks, both the properties are non-null. Typescript agrees for `this.public_property` and only shows `string[]` as its type. However, it says the type of `this.#private_property` is still `string[] | null`. Why is that?

Comment: Might be a Typescript bug, assigning `this.#private_property` to a variable turns the type into `string[]` somehow. `const a = this.$private_property`

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a TypeScript bug.

> The type of `this.#privateProperty` is narrowed to `string[]`. It's just the tooltip that reports the wrong type.

Issue is tracked here: [#43346](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43346)